# How to check all values in List of Class are same or not?

Tags: c#

I need help to write a function or logic to find if all values in my `List` of type class (named `Stack`) are equal or not. So it will return either `true` or `false`.

```
public class Stack
{
    public string Key         { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate   { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a class with 3 properties as above.

```
List<Stack> Stack = new List<Stack>();
Stack WOKey = new Stack() { Key = Resource, StartDate = WorkOrderST, EndDate = WorkOrderED };
Stack.Add(WOKey);
```

I have created 2 objects with StartDate and EndDate assigned to them through variables.

So I need a logic or function that will return `true`, if all `StartDate` have all same values (*eg DateTime(2018, 1, 1)*) and as case for EndDate (*eg DateTime (2018, 1, 30)*).

Should I use `foreach` or is it possible with LINQ? I am new to C# so I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Linq`

You can can do the following:

Don't forget to import `using System.Linq;`

```
List<Stack> Unavailability = new List<Stack>
{
        new Stack{  Key = "A", StartDate = new DateTime(2018,1,1), EndDate = new DateTime(2018,1,30) },
        new Stack{  Key = "B", StartDate = new DateTime(2018,1,1), EndDate = new DateTime(2018,1,30)},
        new Stack{  Key = "C", StartDate = new DateTime(2018,1,1), EndDate = new DateTime(2018,1,30)}
};

bool allUnique = Unavailability.Select(_ => new { _.StartDate, _.EndDate }).Distinct().Count() <= 0;
```

What I did here was project the Stack list using the `Select` to a anonymous type with the objects in it that you want to compare.
Now we can use the `Distinct` operator to determin all the distinct values.

If the result is less than or equal to 0 that means all the values are unique and if it is something else that means multiple unique values were found.

Comment: This is a good approach, though verbose and not reusable.  I like MoreLinq's DistinctBy extension method.  Something similar could be built quickly if you don't want to take the package reference to MoreLinq.

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Comment: Hello Matthiee. This is exact what I want. To distinct the StartDate and EndDate to find if it same or not! But I have edited the code in topic, earlier was wrong posted by mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience, Can you help in written the same logic on new code I updated in topic.

Comment: @ZhrezPain What do you mean? Do you need to check if all values in the stack list are unique?

Comment: Hello Matthiee, your answer was similar to what I needed! thank you :) 

My final code:
int flag = Stack.Select(s => new { s.StartDate, s.EndDate }).Distinct().Count();

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty simple with LINQ:

```
bool allSame = Unavailability.All(s => s.StartDate == new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) &&
                                       s.EndDate == new DateTime(2018, 1, 30));
```

The `.All` returns true if every item in the sequence satisfies the condition. See [.NET Enumerable.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_All__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__).

If you want to see if they are all equal, just use the first value...

```
bool allSame = Unavailability.All(s => s.StartDate == Unavailability[0].StartDate &&
                                       s.EndDate == Unavailability[0].EndDate);
```

Comment: Upvote for using LINQ and doing it in a concise manner. This is the right answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, but its giving me some error, cause of my fault of not sharing the exact code I am using in my project. I have altered the topic. Can you please check and help me out again. Also I wont be knowing the Dates, so I cant define it statically in LINQ